# EC2 spawning from nowhere, no autoscaling group found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm having an issue with AWS boxes (EC2) where I terminate the box and it re-spawns. To give context, there is no autoscaling group. Anywhere I can search for some config that might be triggering the launch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the culprit, maybe it can help more people. Apparently, there is a service from AWS called OpsWorks that automates things like Cheff of Puppet, which my company had configured some time ago. That would be checking for instances running and triggering re-provisioning when it didn't see the instance running. [OpsWorks is here](https://console.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/landing/)

Answer (score 3):

I would make sure you don't have a persistent spot request active in your account, and also check to see if you perhaps installed the AWS Instance scheduler - either or both of those could be starting instances on your behalf - (double check the autoscaling group, that is the most obvious reason though)

> If you terminate a running Spot Instance that was launched by a
>   persistent Spot request, the Spot request returns to the open state so
>   that a new Spot Instance can be launched. To cancel a persistent Spot
>   request and terminate its Spot Instances, you must cancel the Spot
>   request first and then terminate the Spot Instances. Otherwise, the
>   persistent Spot request can launch a new instance.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-requests.html#terminating-a-spot-instance

https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/instance-scheduler/

Comment: Sadly no, I don't have Spot request active in my account nor scheduled instances. I just tried killing all boxes at the same time and they haven't come back, I'll give them a solid hour to see if the re-appear, maybe it's another process that's checking missing boxes